# Why is the adjust option in R's logit function failing to adjust my data?

Tags: r

I need to find out why the adjust option in R's logit function (package "car") doesn't seem to be working.

I'm using R 3.2.2 on a project with a data file that has 450K records. The file contains five columns: four discrete variables (allowable value 0, 1, 2 or 3) and the response variable "sharer_prob" (allowable values 0 - 1--the data set contains are no values = 0, but many = 1).

Because it appeared that logit was gagging on the large file (I only have 8GB of RAM on this machine), I created a random sample without replacement("sampleset" contains 4125 records, which R should be able to handle, right?). The first 30 rows of that file look like this:

```
Index    Sympathy Trust Fear Greed  sharer_prob
817394        2     2    1     2    0.369541
167050        1     1    3     2    0.715611
822867        2     3    2     0    0.818810
323684        2     1    0     0    0.636559
515278        2     2    2     0    0.947242
133239        3     3    0     0    0.938594
459271        3     2    0     0    0.647838
29310         3     2    1     1    0.749249
534875        2     2    2     3    0.608888
656900        3     2    0     0    0.653784
418271        3     2    1     0    0.539343
616221        2     1    0     0    0.600135
592467        3     3    0     0    0.798354
905925        3     2    0     0    0.797031
612514        1     1    3     2    0.554193
8564          1     1    3     2    0.498373
319957        3     3    0     0    1.000000
867410        3     2    0     0    0.581564
551327        3     2    0     0    0.671110
864973        3     3    0     0    1.000000
450469        3     1    2     0    0.578244
877834        2     1    0     0    0.291015
410507        3     3    0     0    0.705201
198044        3     3    0     0    0.772060
548567        3     2    0     0    0.799164
435068        3     2    0     0    0.805771
518144        3     2    1     1    0.396816
609747        3     3    0     0    0.814917
398375        2     1    0     0    0.428143
854396        1     1    3     2    0.511154
```

Because I'm trying to identify significant interaction effects among pairs of the input variables, I used the following code to create interaction terms:

```
IX_greed <- sampleset$greed * sampleset$sharer_prob
IX_sympathy <- sampleset$sympathy * sampleset$sharer_prob
IX_fear <- sampleset$fear * sampleset$sharer_prob
IX_trust <- sampleset$trust * sampleset$sharer_prob
```

I used this line of code to try to regress one of the pairs on the logit of the response variable (sharer_prob):

```
lm.FG=lm( logit( sharer_prob, adjust=TRUE ) ~ IX_fear * IX_greed, na.action=NULL, data=sampleset )
```

But R gave the the following error, which indicates that it failed to adjust the values of 1 to 0.975:

```
**Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'**
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong and how to fix it?

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Larry John

Comment: Try `car::logit(1, , TRUE)`. so try `car::logit(1, , 0.001)` for exmaple

Comment: Which is what your error says... as you have probs = 1 in your data

Comment: The second command returned 6.906755

Comment: True, but it was my impression from what little documentation there is that the adjust function is supposed to change 0's to 0.25, 1's to 0.975 and compress all values between them.

Comment: yes but you are overwriting it with TRUE, which equates to one ( i think you pass a real value to adjust )

Comment: An exmaple... `car::logit(1);
car::logit(1, adjust=0.025);
car::logit(1, adjust=0.00001);
car::logit(1, adjust=1);
car::logit(1, adjust=TRUE)`. And just to show TRUE maps to one.. `car::logit(0.6, adjust=1);
car::logit(0.6, adjust=TRUE)`

Comment: Son of a gun. It works exactly the opposite of how I read the doc. Thanks very much for the help. This is a big deal to me!